# Concatenar resultado de laço SQLQuery

Tags: delphi

Possuo um laço que faz uma varredura em uma tabela, preciso que a cada linha uma variável tipo string seja incrementada com os registros respectivos.

Uso `FDQuery` e `FDConnection`.

Segue uma idéia do que preciso

```
var linhas : string;

while not eof do
begin
linhas := linhas + FieldByName('nome').AsString + ', ';
end;
```

Resultado que preciso:

> Maria, Marcos, Ezequiel, ...

Comment: Você consegue fazer essa concatenação usando uma lista ou um vetor? E de uma função que retorna nomes aleatórios?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não tenho ideia de como fazer uma lista ou um vetor.   Usando um DBGrid ele lista certinho. Preciso do campo "NOME" da tabela apenas. No PHP era mais fácil :(

Comment: Você tem diversas peças móveis aqui: concatenação de strings, falar com o banco, determinar fim do laço (talvez outra coisa que eu não consigo ver). Nessas situações, tente isolar o seu problema. Estou tentando sugerir que você teste em um ambiente mais controlado. Tente ir para a peça móvel que não está se encaixando. Você assumiu que não conhece vetores em programação, então sugiro fortemente estudar assuntos mais básicos antes de se aventurar em resgate de informação de banco de dados.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado conforme mencionei o resultado da consulta eu fiz o impasse está no incremento da varável a cada linha que o laço percorre. Para efeitos de entendimento a única coisa que nao estou tendo sucesso é na concatenação. Em relação a não conhecer vetores apenas em Delphi não sou familiarizado. obrigado

Comment: Torne isso claro no texto da pergunta então ;-)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado obrigado por tentar ajudar. Creio que o foco do problema está bem explicitado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var  
  linhas: string;
begin
  FDQuery1.First;
  while not FDQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    linhas := linhas + FDQuery1.FieldByName('nome').AsString + ', ';

    FDQuery1.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Até onde entendi de sua pergunta, o código acima irá atender sua necessidade por concatenar o resultado da Query numa string. Você também pode fazer isso numa StringList, segue o código:

```
var
  linhas: TStringList;
begin
  linhas := TStringList.Create;
  FDQuery1.First;
  while not FDQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    linhas.Add(FDQuery1.FieldByName('nome').AsString);

    FDQuery1.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ezequiel, levando em conta sua necessidade, o primeiro exemplo de código que postei é o que você precisa. Conseguiu aplica-lo?

Comment: Ola Andrey, Funcionou redondinho, acabei usando o primeiro exemplo pois ja atendeu a necessidade. Grande abraço.